# Creating a Unity scene within the Unity Editor, for an already build Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would love to allow players to build there own maps for my Unity game.
In Ark survival gamers are allowed to create there own maps in Unreal Engine.

Is there an equal way for doing the same in the Unity?

Comment: You are basically asking if  loading a map/texture/gameobject dynamically is possible? Yes it is, the way you make your users to create and save these objects it's on your side

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reaction. Riaan Walters answered my question with "Unity Asset Bundles". These are the things I was looking for! 

I suppose this was what you meant? :P

Comment: I didn't know about that strategy, is always nice to know extra resources i was talking about editing a texture, saving it, and then load that texture in the game, but doing it yourself. Asset Bundles seems to do that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, Unity Asset Bundles allows you to create content which can then be loaded by the clients.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager

It's exactly one of the problems asset bundles are meant to solve (among other things)

Comment: I think your answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to create seperate app which will be editor - and will include all the functionalities to build, and save maps.

And in the main game you will need to add some features to just import those files.

I've never heard about anything which could speed up this process.